# Koala::Facebook::AuthenticationError, Error validating access token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, heroku, omniauth, koala

I am using 'omniauth-facebook' to login with facebook.
I am able to successfully login with facebook in locally. But It was failed after deploying to heroku.

I am getting below error:

```
 Koala::Facebook::AuthenticationError (type: OAuthException, code: 190, error_subcode: 467, message: Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error., x-fb-trace-id: GlM51Vo5azj [HTTP 400]):
2016-09-19T10:55:12.265269+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/home_controller.rb:8:in `result
```

**omniauth.rb**

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :facebook, 'XXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
scope: 'publish_actions,email', :provider_ignores_state => true
end
```

I am storing user data in db

**user.rb**

```
 def self.from_omniauth(auth)
where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize do |user|
  user.provider = auth.provider
  user.uid = auth.uid
  user.name = auth.info.name
  user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
  user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
  user.save!
end
```

end

**sessions_controller**

```
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to result_home_path(user.id)
  end
```

It seems user data is not updating properly when user logged in. Help me anyone faced similar problem.

Comment: Hey @vjnan369, how did you resolve this?